# Parsing OFX or SGML in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sgml, ofx

How do I parse OFX in iOS? OFX is formatted in SGML, and I can't find any good parsers to use in C or Objective-C on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [libofx](http://libofx.sourceforge.net).  It depends on OpenJADE for SGML but I've gotten them both to compile and work on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few challenges here:

(1) OFX 1.x documents are SGML-based, while 2.x documents are XML-based, so if you know you will only deal with 2.x documents you could probably use an XML parser.

(2) If you do have to deal with 1.x documents, you'll have some code-lifting ahead of you.  SGML in general and OFX 1.x in particular do not enforce close tags for simple types.  That means you'll see things like:

```
<INVACCTFROM>
    <BROKERID>Fidelity Investments
    <ACCTID>FidRoth
</INVACCTFROM>
```

Parsing this kind of thing will be tricky unless you provide your own schema logic, or pre-process the data to a more "valid" format.  An example of the latter, while not in C/Obj-C/C++, is given on [Scott Hanselman's blog.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PostprocessingAutoClosedSGMLTagsWithTheSGMLReader.aspx)

Good resources on OFX can be found [here.](http://www.ofx.net/)

Comment: Yes I do need to deal with 1.x. Still looking for some C/Obj-C/C++ pre-processing, or libraries before I built it all myself.